# Are cholim obligated to please their wives?

Tags: halacha, marriage, sexuality, choleh-sick

To me it is clear that if (G-d forbid) a person is sick to the point that it will kill them, or that (G-d forbid) they will get their wife sick, there's obviously no obligation to please their wife (fulfill the requirement of *ona*).  If the doctor tells them not to, also it is clear to me that they are not obligated to (and maybe obligated not to).

So that raises the questions:

- Minimally how sick should one be for that obligation to be nullified?
- What about extended illnesses (e.g., G-d forbid, a broken hip or leukemia)?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman You need to source your premise. Why would being sick free him of his obligations to his wife? If I owe you a hundred dollars and I become paralyzed and I cannot get the money to you, do I not owe you the money anymore? This man entered a contract and it is his obligation to fulfill it. From a purely technical, legalistic point of view, I would say that such sickness, if it was not expected at the time of the marriage, is grounds for the woman to demand a divorce, even if it would not be nice of her. I therefore cannot accept your premise until you provide a valid source.

Comment: @DovF That's a good point. Not sure of that.

Comment: Why isn't this a case of having to ask a rav a specific shaila for a specific set of circumstances? As far as I know, there are two categories of cholim: 'she yesh bo sakanah' and 'she ein bo sakanah.'For 'yesh bo sakanah,' everything goes out the window. Therefore, you should edit your question to ask if a male in the categoray of 'choleh she ein bo sakanah' is obligated in 'ona.' That would be a much more productive question and to the point - unless you're trying to ask something else which you have not yet articulated.

Comment: @Shemmy This isn't really specific (many married men get sick), and I'm not asking for a psak.  I think the question "Minimally how sick" implies that I'm looking for an upper bound.  If that upper bound were *sheyesh bo sakanah*, that's a legitimate answer to the question. DoubleAA has a less-restrictive and more-sourced answer below.

Comment: The question is legitimate. Rambam (and subsequently S"A) uses the words "עומדים אותו" - literally "they evaluate him", implying a Beis Din of three, where the husband was sued by his wife. The Halakha does not set a bar of illness, instead every case is judged personally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch discusses this issue (Even HaEzer 76).

In Seif 3, he comments regarding the standard *onot* as fixed by profession:

> בד"א, במי שגופו בריא ויכול לקיים העונה הקצובה לו, אבל מי שאינו בריא אינו חייב אלא לפי מה שאומדין אותו שיכול לקיים. ‏
>   In what situation do [the above times] apply? For someone who's body is healthy and is able to perform his set *onah*. But for someone who is not healthy, he is only obligated according to what he is evaluated to be able to perform.

But note that in Seif 11 he writes:

> ואם חלה או תשש כחו ואינו יכול לבעול, ימתין ששה חדשים עד שיבריא, שאין לך עונה גדולה מזו, אחר כך, או יטול ממנה רשות או יוציא ויתן כתובה
>   And if he became sick or weak and he is unable to perform his *onah* requiremnets, he can wait up to six months to get better, for that is the longest standard *onah* [that of a sailor]; then, he must either ask her permission to delay further [which is in general permissable] or he must divorce her and pay her ketubah.

So in summary, one may delay his *onah* requirements due to illness up to six months. If he still is too sick, then his wife may grant him more time or sue for divorce.

Comment: Shulchan Aruch (Even HaEzer 76) only cites Rambam's Ishut 14 adding nothing new.

Comment: @AlBerko Only adding his stamp of approval.