# Mikvah and illness

Tags: women, sexuality, mikvah-ritual-bath, niddah, choleh-sick

My understanding is that, as a general rule, a healthy woman may not delay going to the Mikvah for her own (or even her husband's) convenience.

But I'm wondering if there are sources discussing whether a woman should or shouldn't go to Mikvah when she and/or her husband has a non-life threatening illness that may be made worse by going (eg., flu, strep, ear infection)?

Does it matter if either she or her husband may be contagious?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17437/759

Comment: I would think that even a cold might be passed onto the other women there. Shouldn't that also be a concern?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a great deal of particulars depending on the case; I strongly recommend you contact yoatzot.org, who have dealt with dozens (hundreds) of such cases. Deena Zimmerman published an article in *Tradition* a few years ago specifically addressing mikvah concerns that have arisen in cases of breast cancer, in which all *piskei halacha* have been validated by Rabbi Yehuda Herzl Henkin, shlit'a.

Comment: Ok, but I'm specifically talking about non-life threatening illness.

Comment: I fail to fully understand the three questions. Do you mean that the husband wants her to go but she doesnt want to because it will make her more ill.

Comment: Shalom, I hope I've edited the question in a way that clarifies it for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to my wife, she has gone with a flu and bronchitis, but wouldn't go with an ear infection because that will definitely make her more sick.  She even knows of people who have gone the same day as getting stitches.  Also, sometimes a Mikvah lady will not allow a woman to go, if she has a disease or sickness which is contagious.