# Wife's conjugal rights

Tags: halacha, women, marriage, sexuality, divorce

I understand that a wife has a conjugal rights depending on the occupation of the husband (2 times a week, 1 time a week, on Friday night, one time a month, 1 time in 6 months, 1 time a year)

And that if she does not receive it she can demand a divorce

Does this include when the man gets old, (can not tie his sandal while standing on one foot)
And physically can not perform his obligation.

Sources and/or details please, thank you

Comment: "can not tie his sandal standing on one foot". "can not tie his sandal standing on one foot". Nope. Repeating it doesn't help.

Comment: @msh210 I do not understand?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17461/759

Comment: a lead here. http://www.jewishvaluesonline.org/420 especially Rabbi Stuart Grant's answer

Comment: @DannySchoemann Is there a difference between old and sick regarding this law?

Comment: @hazoriz - no. As the other answer quotes - ואם חלה או תשש כחו - the underlying difference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**, the wife of an old fellow cannot demand a divorce.

**Sources and/or details**

You are only quoting half the requirements - occupation. **Health** also plays a role. See Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer [סימן עו - חיוב עונה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01974_part_4.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) for the full details.

> **א:** עוֹנָתָהּ כֵּיצַד, כָּל אִישׁ חַיָּב  בְּעוֹנָה **כְּפִי כֹּחוֹ** וּכְפִי מְלַאכְתּוֹ. וְהַטַּיָּלִים, עוֹנָתָם בְּכָל  לַיְלָה

Conjugal rights: Each person's obligation depends on his **health** and his occupation. E.g. הַטַּיָּלִים - healthy, wealthy people who have nothing much to do all day except stroll around leisurely -  their wives deserve their conjugal rights nightly.

My *translation* of הַטַּיָּלִים is per the  באר היטב who clarifies as per the טור:

> **לילה**. היינו אדם בטל שאין לו מלאכה והוא **ברי**' ומעונג ואינו פורע מס ואינו הולך בדרך

In other words, your first sentence should read: `a wife has a conjugal rights depending on the health and occupation of the husband.`

Comment: @doubleDD From doubleDD comment above I see that if he gets old and can not do once in 6 months then the wife can demand a divorce, is this correct? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17461/5120

Comment: @hazoriz - correct. I think this question is actually a dup of that one (http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17461/501) now that I have read it.

Comment: So any old man's wife can demand a divorce (we can not say that it is usnal that he will loose his power when he gets older, and his wife was aware of this and agreed (forgave his responsibility (so she will not be able to demand a divorce)) to say married in such a case), so it is good advice that before a Jew gets married he makes the condition with his bride that if he gets older she will not demand a divorce?

Comment: @hazoriz No, it is not good advice. If she wants to leave, let her leave. That's good advice.

Comment: @DoubleAA very nice, but money is an issue also (kesuba and maybe nedunya), the advice will help the man keep his money, since "she wants to leave"

Comment: @hazoriz I wouldn't call it an "issue". The nedunya was hers. She should get it back. End of story. Sure, one could be a Naval Birshut HaTorah and seriously harm someone emotionally for some money, but that is never a good idea and advising people how to do it easier is wrong.

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you sure she keeps it if she is moredes

Comment: @hazoriz Who said anything about moredes? If she asks for a divorce he should give it. No rebelling by anyone.

Comment: @DoubleAA And pay for it? (She is demanding a divorce why should he pay?)

Comment: @hazoriz Pay for what? The Beis Din fee? He agreed when they got married to give her some money if they get divorced. That's a risk he took. (I agree it's probably polite of her to decline the money if she initiated the proceedings.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30038/discussion-between-hazoriz-and-double-aa).