# If a bride did not reveal a medical condition before the marriage is it a mekach taus (annuled)

Tags: halacha, marriage, shidduchim-dating, engagement-shidduch

@DonielF in a comment [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84852/is-a-man-obligated-to-seek-a-medical-remedy-to-fulfill-onah?noredirect=1#comment267410_84852) seem to clame that (by the end of Ketubot) it is written that a marriage can be annuled (as a mekach tous) if the bride (I guess or her father) withheld information about her medical condition (but did reveal her  vows,  mumim (phisical deformaties) and  her virgin status)

If this true?
(If yes is it all medical conditions?
(If not which ones?))
Where is this written?

Thank You

Comment: [Am I on-topic?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478/)

Comment: Consider just asking what the basic rules are for mekah taut. Applying them to every given medical condition, is too broad, and probably primarily opinion based.

Comment: @mevaqesh I never saw it applied to medical conditions so I am looking for any precident that yes

Comment: @mevaqesh I think I read once epelepsy is one

Comment: @mevaqesh I am wrong epelepsy is a mum https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.39.4

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is true. Part of the discussion can be found in kesuvos 73b. However, it is not necessarily a simple case. In fact, many cases will have a get issued in order to avoid the complexities, though this causes problems if the woman wants to marry a kohen.

As an example, Rabbi Hershel Shachter writes [Making a Farce of the Halacha](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2013/12/rav-herschel-schacter-ridiculous-heter.html) discusses the situation in which someone attempts to use the concept of *mekach taus* to free an agunah.

> It is important to keep in mind that Rav Moshe Feinstein clearly
>   states that the negative condition must be preexisting and so severe
>   that no reasonable person would tolerate it - and the spouse must
>   leave immediately upon discovering it. In addition a psak of mekach
>   taus based entirely upon negative reports from the wife - without the
>   husband being directly evaulated by a neutral expert therapist - is
>   clearly invalid and indicative of biased poskim.

He states

> Furthermore, kiddushin (entering into a marriage) apparently requires
>   a level of da'as even higher than mekach u'memkar (see the famous
>   comment of the Ran to Nedarim 87a. See also Beis Yitzchak 5748, pg.
>   241). In order to nullify a marriage by reason of kiddushei ta'us
>   (because of lack of da'as), one would presumably require an even more
>   obvious ta'us than what might be sufficient to invalidate a purchase
>   of stocks or a sale of real estate. Indeed, the Talmud (Kesubos 73b)
>   describes certain cases that based on the general principles of ta'us
>   would qualify as kiddushei ta'us and as such would be invalid and
>   should not need a get. Nevertheless, the gemara declares that a get is
>   required- either as a chumra d'rabanan (rabbinical stringency), or
>   perhaps even because of a safek d'oraysa (legal doubt on the biblical
>   level). It is plain from this source that we are more reluctant to
>   invalidate a wedding on ta'us grounds than to declare a mekach taus on
>   a business transaction.
>
> To declare a marriage a kiddushei ta'us because the wife didn't
>   realize that the husband would be unsuccessful in holding down a job
>   and earning a living is simply unacceptable. To invalidate a kiddushin
>   due to ta'us the halacha requires an extraordinary mum gadol (very
>   significant defect), with a very obvious umdana d'muchach (compelling
>   assumption) that no reasonable woman would agree to marry such a man
>   (see Teshuvos Beis Halevi, vol. 3, pg. 23).

There is an analysis of some classic cases at [Classic Cases: Mekach Ta'ut, Get and Annulment](http://ccs.infospace.com/ClickHandler.ashx?encp=ld%3d20170820%26app%3d1%26c%3dpchmeta4balancemail%26s%3dpchmeta4balancemail%26rc%3dpchmeta4balancemail%26dc%3d%26euip%3d71.179.210.219%26pvaid%3d19689cae474d47b7b5bfb0288776abd5%26dt%3dDesktop%26fct.uid%3deff32cb2dc16473eb1dd871b8228a27c%26en%3dy2HsFdiwRo5kCpKO8cvIHm3k6rwC7isXcbaVOv73DgSMe1SPUf1e2w%252buj32XD%252bbbYV4U9pqagRSy%252feXDMKGWiMdIHu2Q4xBDe2IZxbDlis8%253d%26coi%3d1494%26npp%3d7%26p%3d0%26pp%3d0%26mid%3d9%26ep%3d7%26ru%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fwww.jofa.org%252fsites%252fdefault%252ffiles%252fuploaded_files%252fclassic_case_studies1.pdf%26du%3dwww.jofa.org%252fsites%252fdefault%252ffiles%252fuploaded_files%252fclassic_case...%26pct%3dhttp%253a%252f%252fsct.pch.com%252fimages%252f__kl.gif%253fun%253dB02F3AC1-A606-4926-9349-6CAB7C6338A3%2526uid%253d49ea977fc3c1da6f28078aff1a55e39f%2526mobility%253ddesktop%2526searchID%253d49ea977fc3c1da6f28078aff1a55e39f1503237359966%26hash%3d40EFD78D519587A572B7D14044B34647&ap=8&cop=main-title&om_userid=z18W6nt2sgbXlcQfIHtv&om_sessionid=PfZurtWIcAYsv9zUP8ky&om_pageid=AbC93ByRdQOvdc0KIq8B&om_nextpage=true)

Comment: +1 but I see nothing about medical condition, only vows, mums (not any mum but from a list), and virginity

Comment: Yes! That’s exactly the Gemara I was thinking of. I came across it in Shav Shmaytsa, so I wasn’t paying much attention to the source so much as the sugya.